# Goldschmidt division example with estimates?

Tags: arithmetic

I have found in Gonzalez/Diaz-Herrera/Tucker: *Computing Handbook* an example for the Goldschmidt division in the case of real numbers. The example is the following:
\begin{align}
N_0 &= N = 0.625  \\
D_0 &= D = 0.75  \\
F_1 &= 1.3& & &\text{Table Look Up} \\
N_1 &= N_0 \cdot F_1 = 0.625 \cdot 1.3 &= 0.8125&  &\text{Multiply} \\
D_1 &= D_0 \cdot F_1 = 0.75 \cdot 1.3 &= 0.975&  &\text{Multiply} \\
F_2 &= 2 - D_1 = 2 - 0.975 &= 1.025&  &\text{Subtract} \\
N_2 &= N_1 \cdot F_2 = 0.8125 \cdot 1.025 &= 0.8328125&  &\text{Multiply} \\
D_2 &= D_1 \cdot F_2 = 0.975 \cdot 1.025 &= 0.999375&  &\text{Multiply} \\
F_3 &= 2 - D_2 = 2 - 0.999375 &= 1.000625&  &\text{Subtract} \\
N_3 &= N_2 \cdot F_3 = 0.8328125 \cdot 1.000625 &= 0.8333330078125&  &\text{Multiply} \\
(D_3 &= D_2 \cdot F_3 = 0.999375 \cdot 1.000625 &= 0.999999609375)&  &\text{(Multiply)} \\
\end{align}
[image]

Even though the example is quite simple, I have problems in two parts:

- How to get the estimate of 1.3 as the value of F1, it mentions one table, but how to use it?
- In the case of division with integers, the procedure is the same? I have been trying to check it up one example for this case, but I only found explanations that use binaries and real numbers. If somebody could post an example of how to do this procedure with integer numbers would be great.

Thanks

Comment: (In chapter 20 by Swartzlander, E. E., featuring in the introduction of his own *Computer Arithmetic: Volume II*, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try and divide 6250 by 75.
First, almost arbitrarily re-interpret as fixed point numbers 62.50 and 00.75.
Look up the reciprocal of leading digit .7: 1.4 $= F_1$
Products: $N_1 = 62.5 \cdot 1.4 = 87.5$, $D_1 = .75 \cdot 1.4 = 1.05$
$F_2 = 2-1.05 = .95$, $N_2 = 87.5\cdot.95 = 83.12(5)$
($D_2 = 1.05\cdot.95 = .99(75)$, but talking *integers*, 83 *is* the quotient)

With *integers*, one may pre-check the absolute value of the dividend for being smaller than the divisor. To profit most from *the table of reciprocals*, the operands conventionally are scaled such that the divisor is in a smallish range, its most significant digit in a known position.
Choosing the size of the reciprocal table is a trade-off between small table and small number of iterations.
The most significant part/first few digits of the divisor are used to index the table, yielding a reciprocal with a similar number of digits of resolution.
Thinking of the bit patterns as fixed point numbers with more significant half integers, less significant part fractions is just a convenience - otherwise, I'd have to hand-wave about scaling all the time.

Comment: (The approximation `1.3` from the example is due to using two digits (.75) in stead of the single one used in above answer.)